# Characteristic of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is it possible for a non-commutative ring with no zero divisor to have finite characteristic property?

Comment: what is the finite characteristic property? Do you simply mean that the ring has finite characteristic? what is infinite characteristic then?

Comment: The enveloping algebra of a non-abelian Lie algebras define over a field of positive characteristic is a non-commutative integral domain of positive characteristic. There are many, many other examples...

Comment: Just take noncommutative polynomials in two variables over a finite field.