# Is a unity ring with characteristic $2$ always commutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is a unity ring with characteristic $2$ always commutative?
I believe it is not, but I cannot find a counterexample.

Comment: [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482353/characteristic-of-a-ring).

Comment: Please forgive me when I say that you should always know a basic example for a non-commutative unital ring, i.e., a matrix ring over a finite field, for example.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde no problem, I am just a beginner when it comes to abstract algebra. $\mathcal{M} _3(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ solves my question.

Answer (score 5):

No. An obvious counterexample is:

Take $F_2\langle x,y\rangle$, the free algebra on two noncommuting indeterminates over the field of two elements.

Another one would be $M_2(F_2)$, a square matrix ring over the same field.